# hover effect with img inside anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-6

I am trying to build a script with javascript and jquery that has one element react when the mouse is hovered over another element.  I've had some great help getting to this point but I think I'm messing something up here.  I have it working in one direction but not the other.  In the direction it is working, there is text inside an anchor element.  In the direction it's not working there is an image inside the anchor.  That may be messing me up, not sure.  I've posted a simplified version of it all here: http://jsfiddle.net/vZAYY/14/
It seems like the javascript isn't finding the li element (it returns -1)

One other thing that is odd is that on the full site (which I'm running locally) neither works, though to build the js fiddle I just copied the code directly. It's on a site with drupal and there the script is returning -1 from hovers on both elements.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A minor update, using `closest()` instead of multiple calls to `parent()`. Could you reduce this to a minimal example? And clearly state what's meant to happen when you hover a link/image?

Comment: I tried using closest() but couldn't get it to work.  Ideally what I'm trying to have happen is that when an image is hovered over, the link (text) changes color and the image becomes slightly opaque - and the same thing happens when the link (text) is hovered over.  I could change the classes to match if it makes the javascript easier.  The hard part is I don't know a lot about javascript if you couldn't tell.  Any advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mess but if something returns `-1` it has to be the `index()` function. Can't say for sure but your problem could be here:

```
var x = $(this).parent().parent().parent("li").index();
$(".mainNavigation ul li:eq(" + x + ")").addClass("active");
```

I'm not sure `parent().parent().parent('li').index()` is the best idea. I mean, `index()` takes a context that you can specify. It's a good idea to cache your selectors beforehand.
In the second line instead of `:eq` I would use `eq()` which will be faster and more predictable.